# incorrect date addition for February month in moment js

Tags: momentjs

Using Moment js to do date manipulation. Below are my code.

startdate = "28/2/2018" (comes from angular html page)

```
var dateObj = new Date(startdate);  
var momentObj = moment(dateObj);  
var momentString = momentObj.add(1, 'months').format('DD-MM-YYYY');

var graceperioddate = moment(momentString,'DD-MM-YYYY').add(10, 'days').format('DD-MM-YYYY')
```

Expected Result : 10-03-2018

Actual Result : 07-03-2018

Please help fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the reason for wrong answer.
If we use format ('YYYY-MM-DD') it solves the problem. So in below code formatted with ('YYYY-MM-DD') and got correct result as 10-03-2018.

```js
var momentString = momentObj.add(1, 'months').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
var graceperioddate = moment(momentString,'DD-MM-YYYY').add(10, 'days').format('DD-MM-YYYY')
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I have not enough reputation to comment.
I just tried your code snippet with `moment.js` version 2.20.1

```
"dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.20.1"
}
```

but I could not reproduce the behavior you described (debugging in vscode 1.20.0):
[image]

Which version of `moment.js` are you using? Maybe you want to try it with version *2.20.1*? Hope I could help.

Comment: you are correct, the above code works fine, in reality root cause for the bug is different. So editing my question.

Comment: Furthermore, as you can read in [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/date-and-time-strings-javascript#other-date-formats) the `Date()` constructor does **not support** dates formatted like `DD/MM/YYYY` but it **supports** `MM/DD/YYYY`.